# How to obtain all the radio urls of xiph.org

Tags: php, webradio

Is there any way to obtain all the URLs from [xiph.org](http://dir.xiph.org)? Is there a way to query directly the site to obtain a specified radio or a specified category of radios from a web application?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not going to violate any copyrights?

Comment: I hope not! It is not a commercial application, it is just a player which takes the streams from xiph.org, there are hundred of radio players online and on the phones.

Comment: I don't see any radio/stream URLs there. Where are they?

Comment: Do you mean on xiph.org? The streams are on http://dir.xiph.org/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've had a look at a few of those streams on that site.

If you open the `XSPF` files in a text editor, you get some XML, with the streams wrapped in the `<location>` tab.

You're going to have to setup some kind of crawler for this. I'll just make a simple one for you.

```
//define the link
$link = 'http://dir.xiph.org/';

//get the contents
$contents = file_get_contents($link);

preg_match_all('|"/listen/(.*)/listen.m3u"|',$contents,$match);


//define xspf link array
$xspfLinks = array();

//define default link
$xspfLink = 'http://dir.xiph.org/listen/';

//define final stream array
$finalStream=array();

foreach ($match[1] as $id )
{
    //assign ID to default link and throw it in the array
    $xspfLinks[]=$xspfLink.$id.'/listen.xspf';

}

// now loop through that array
foreach ($xspfLinks as $hehehe )
{
    //download xspf file
    $xspf = file_get_contents($hehehe);

    if(preg_match('|<location>(.*)</location>|',$xspf,$heheMatch))
    {

        //put stream url in final array
        $finalStream[]=$heheMatch[1];
        //test it
        echo 'HEHEHEHE I just stole:'.$heheMatch[1]."<br>";

    }
}

//now do as you please with $finalStream (it will contain all your stream urls)
```

I just done it all for you -_-. But yeah, that should work.

Oh and one more thing, If you are being silly and stealing those streams when you shouldn't be, I will not be held responsible.

Comment: Thank you I will try it later, why should it be illegal? I can open all the streams one by one and it is not illegal. I can download a plugin for an audio player and listen all the streams. So please tell me what could be illegal in all that.

Comment: Yes, it's okay to open them. But that's not what you're doing here. You're **taking** them. You could use this to setup your own app, duplicating them. And I never said it was illegal, but It could easily be breaching a copyright law.

Comment: My intent is to create a little database with the urls, so the app can open it instead to open each time the site to listen a new radio.

Comment: Please I need to know if it is not legal or violate the copyright

Comment: So now you want **me** to read their copyright laws, even after spending like half an hour writing that code for you? Hahaha, you're funny.

Comment: I'm not asking that, I thought you knew the subject :D

Comment: I'm here to help people with their code. Not with their legal issues.

Answer (score 0):

Xiph.org is working on a [JSON API (#tkt1958)](https://trac.xiph.org/ticket/1958) now. The encoding is still vastly broken due to mysqls `CONCAT(json_object(m.stream_name...` query.

But even with a regex JSON extraction it's speedier and easier to use than processing the old `yp.xml`.